# How to combine two Excel =filter( ) functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to filter a table twice.

First, I want to exclude rows if "Tour-Nr." equals to a specific value:

`=FILTER(Data, ISERROR(MATCH(Data[Tour-Nr.], B3:B8, 0)) * ISERROR(MATCH(Data[Unt. Nr.], D3:D8, 0)))`

Second I want to filter like that

`=IFERROR(FILTER(`
`Data, (Data[POD] = "No") * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Beladestelle Ist (IOP)])) * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Entladestelle Ist (IOD)]))`
`+ (Data[POD] = "No") * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Beladestelle Ist (IOP)])) + (Data[POD] = "No") * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Entladestelle Ist (IOD)]))`
`+ (Data[POD] = "No") + (Data[POD] = "Yes") * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Beladestelle Ist (IOP)]))`
`+ (Data[POD] = "Yes") * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Beladestelle Ist (IOP)])) * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Entladestelle Ist (IOD)]))`
`+ (Data[POD] = "Yes") * (ISBLANK(Data[Abfahrt Entladestelle Ist (IOD)]))),`
`"No Tours Available")`

I dont know how to use + and * in this case.

Comment: First, FILTER formula is not available in Excel 2007, correct tag. Second, what is your question?

Comment: I don't see a copyable data sample nor a screenshot of your desired output. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)